# Utilizar UUID como id de usuarios en laravel passport

Tags: laravel, passport

Estoy trabajando en laravel passport con personal tokens, el id de mis usuarios es de tipo `uuid` para evitar que puedan ser adivinados.

Todo funciona bien en relación al usuario, el problema viene a la hora de generar un token:

```
$token = $user->createToken('My Token', ['read-phrase'])->accessToken;
```

Cuando la id de mi usuario es un `int` todo funciona bien, pero cuando es `uuid` obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'tokenable_id' at row 1
```

He reemplazado en todas las migraciones el tipo de dato por `uuid`, para ser más especificos:

```
//oauth_auth_codes
$table->uuid('user_id')->index();
$table->uuid('client_id');

//oauth_access_tokens
$table->uuid('user_id')->nullable()->index();
$table->uuid('client_id');

//oauth_clients
$table->uuid('user_id')->nullable()->index();

//oauth_personal_access_clients
$table->uuid('client_id');
```

Pila de seguimiento del error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'tokenable_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (My Token, 5eaef6980a34301b04b26602d92ed224bf17867121d5f352b60b738ee5af3feb, ["read-phrase"], 00d1783b-6904-492a-a249-b4e85a3ec70c, App\Models\User, 2020-10-15 15:12:49, 2020-10-15 15:12:49)) in file C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 671

#0 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(631): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `pe...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(465): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('insert into `pe...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(417): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('insert into `pe...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor.php(32): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert('insert into `pe...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2871): Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor->processInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), 'insert into `pe...', Array, 'id')
#5 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(1496): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#6 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(892): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
#7 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(857): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#8 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(720): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder))
#9 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php(298): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#10 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(263): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany->Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken))
#11 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php(299): tap(Object(Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\HasApiTokens.php(49): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany->create(Array)
#13 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\app\Http\Controllers\AccountsController.php(38): App\Models\User->createToken('My Token', Array)
#14 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\AccountsController->login(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('login', Array)
#17 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(255): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\AccountsController), 'login')
#18 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(197): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#19 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(691): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#20 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(103): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), Array)
#25 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(55): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api', Object(Closure))
#26 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api')
#27 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(693): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#29 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(668): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(634): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#31 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(623): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(87): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#48 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 C:\xampp74\htdocs\phrases\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 {main}
```

¿Qué mas debo cambiar para que funcione la creación de tokens con mi id de usuario como UUID?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es la columna donde almacenas el `uuid`?

Comment: @BetaM En las migraciones definí todo como ````uuid````,  en la base de datos se traduce en ````char(36)````. La generación de claves ````uuid```` la estoy realizando con el paquete de  ````Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid````.

Comment: La longitud del tipo de dato no es la adecuada, tu uuids ocupan un espacio mayor al que la definición da permiso por eso los trunca, deberás o ampliar la longitud del dato actual (si lo permite) o usar otro tipo de dato (**prueba con esto que te digo como opción**)

Comment: @BetaM Me he confundido, todo este tiempo he estado mirando otra tabla, al revisar la tabla, en realidad en la migración está como ````$table->morphs('tokenable');```` lo que se traduce en la base de datos como dos columnas ````tokenable_type varchar(255)```` y ````tokenable_id  bigint(20)````. Creo que llegado a este punto el error se cuenta solo. 
He reemplazado el tipo por ````uuidMorphs()```` y ahora todo parece funcionar bien en relación a la generación del token.

Comment: Deberías publicar la solución para no dejar abandonada la pregunta y que otros y otras con esa duda encuentren solución

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución fue cambiar el tipo de dato en la migración `personal_access_tokens`

Originalmente la columna está definida como:

`$table->morphs('tokenable');`

Lo que se traduce en agregar dos nuevas columnas con los siguientes tipos de datos:

1. (_id) = UNSIGNED BIGINT
2. (_type) = VARCHAR

La solución fue reemplazarlo por:

`$table->uuidMorphs('tokenable');`

Lo que genera dichas columnas como:

1. (_id) = CHAR(36)
2. (_type) = VARCHAR(255)

Si hay más dudas respecto al tipo de dato puede revisar [Laravel Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada cuando el sistema te lo permita

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho y funciono perfecto con laravel 8